# Positioning background image hover another image with css, z-index?

Tags: css, positioning, background-image

I've made this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gableroux/SzGe8/#base) to exactly illustrate what I want to accomplish. Basically
I want to make a background image show hover another using css. I tried z-index but it doesn't work. I tried inserting the top image using img tag, but it's not a very good idea as it's part of the design and not an element of the page.

Note: I don't want the image to hide the text too ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Won't this work?

http://jsfiddle.net/SzGe8/6/

You need to place footer-top-image inside the footer.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick all I needed was `position: relative; top: -40px` with div inside the other as you pointed, I also wanted the text to go up a little too so here is my final result: http://jsfiddle.net/gableroux/SzGe8/15/

Thanks again :)